# Derivation of existence of energy band gap in semiconductor (solid State)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, quasiparticles

I am looking for both a mathematical and a physical reason for energy band gap in metals. For Physical reason, I was told that at each reciprocal lattice, you could have Bragg scattering, that would cause the band gap, but this does not really make full sense to me.

For a mathematical reason, do we have to solve the Schrodinger equation? Before we can see why?

Similarly these kind of bang gap have been found in a diatomic chain and I have seen the derivation which makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the fermi-dirac state density distribution:

$ f(E) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp^{\frac{E}{k_{B}T}}} $

[Fermi-Dirac Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzHtT.jpg)

(Derived from the Boltzmann canonical formulae)

This shows that as the temperature of a system of spin 1/2 particles increases, the density of states lowers itself over more states.

To model the solid-state of a metal, we take the k-space of dimension:

$ V = (\frac{\pi}{L})^3 $

and the fermi-sphere, of radius equal to the fermi wave-vector:

$V = \frac{4}{24} \pi r^{3} $

because $ r = k_{F} $ and add factor of two for each spin +-1/2 of N, number of electrons in volume, then you can get:

$ k_{F} = (\frac{2\pi^{2}V}{N})^{1/3} $

Where N is the number of electrons, generally $ N_{A} \times N_{e} $, V is the volume.

This enables us to find the fermi-energy:

$ E_{F} = \frac{\hbar^{2}k_{F}^{2}}{2m_{e}} $

In the first formula and graph, this energy defines what energy the states reach at 0K.

This distribution of states relates to electricity due to the [Band Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSJji.gif) of metals, of the valency and conduction bands.
As you can see in the image the fermi-energy is plotted on the axes for different types of metal and DOS along the bottom stands for density of states which is the first formula.